# How can I regain an admin account on my iMac?

Tags: high-sierra, login, administrator, single-user

I have seen this question several times but no clear answer. I changed the password on the admin user account and It saved it as a standard user. I just bought the Mac so I’m a newbie.

- I have tried booting into single user mode so I can creat another admin user but my wireless keyboard driver isn’t loading quick enough before it boots up.
- I have also tried changing the password using command+R and when I get to sign in with Apple ID it says not connected to internet and won’t let me do that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in Recovery mode, not single-user. In Recovery mode, you are not started up from your normal system volume, so files are not at their usual paths.

I had to go into terminal and type

```
rm /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

*Note: that if your main volume is named something other than "Macintosh HD", you need to substitute that at the appropriate place; also, there must be a space after "rm" and cannot be one before ".AppleSetupDone".*

Also, standard dscl commands will not work as expected in Recovery mode. Once done exit terminal and restart. Upon restart I was able to select a new user with admin privilege.

What a beating !!